# What is the reference return type?

Tags: c++, types, iterator

Looking through https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator i found this piece of code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
 
template<long FROM, long TO>
class Range {
public:
    // member typedefs provided through inheriting from std::iterator
    class iterator: public std::iterator<
                        std::input_iterator_tag,   // iterator_category
                        long,                      // value_type
                        long,                      // difference_type
                        const long*,               // pointer
                        long                       // reference
                                      >{
        long num = FROM;
    public:
        explicit iterator(long _num = 0) : num(_num) {}
        iterator& operator++() {num = TO >= FROM ? num + 1: num - 1; return *this;}
        iterator operator++(int) {iterator retval = *this; ++(*this); return retval;}
        bool operator==(iterator other) const {return num == other.num;}
        bool operator!=(iterator other) const {return !(*this == other);}
        reference operator*() const {return num;}
    };
    iterator begin() {return iterator(FROM);}
    iterator end() {return iterator(TO >= FROM? TO+1 : TO-1);}
};
```

I'm really confused about this line `reference operator*() const {return num;}`. I have searched on this return type, but haven't found any information. I'm pretty newbie in C++, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `reference` is inherited from `std::iterator` If you look above the code you copied here you'll see it in the Member Types section of the same document.

Comment: And `std::iterator` is deprecated...

Comment: [Here you can see](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) that `reference` for this instantiation of `std::iterator` is `long&`.